# Running postgresql query with backslash

Tags: sql

I've been able to connect to a Vertica database, and also been able to run a SELECT query. But I'm not being able to run a query with a backslash in it. (Vertica has commands like postgresql.) The command I'm trying to run is `\d;`. I've tried variations like below with a varying number of backslashes without success:

`SQLExecute[conn, "\\\d;"]`

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I should add that the error I'm getting is this:
`JDBC::error: [Vertica][VJDBC](4856) ERROR: Syntax error at or near "\" >>`

Comment: Three backslashes cannot be correct. *Mathematica* requires that each one be escaped, once, as ``\\``. If Vertica requires an additional escape, you will have to enter four backslashes for each one you want to appear in the query. Beyond that, I have no suggestions, since I've never used this software--sorry.

Comment: @OleksandrR. What is the Vertica connection string? It's native into Mathematica?

Answer (score 1):

This is more a workaround than an answer. Schema information for all tables is also available in a table. In the case of vertica, a query like the following would get all schemas:

```
columns={"table_schema","table_name","column_name","data_type","data_type_length","is_nullable","column_default"};
SQLExecute[conn,"SELECT "<>StringJoin[Riffle[columns, ", "]]<>" FROM v_catalog.columns"];
```